# Google maps and knockoutjs

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, knockout.js

I am making a single page app where in the second view I need to display the Google map. I am using the Google maps API where the map object is to be created.

```
 var map = new google.maps.Map(mapId, {
        zoom: 5,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(55, 11),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 });
```

The parameter `mapId` is giving me a problem. The view contains a div with id say "mapId", but I am not able to get the id and so the map cannot be displayed. I tried HTML binding, attribute binding but it does not work. I am new to knockout. Please suggest some method

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding why you can't get the id of the element? Is the second view a modal/dialog?

Comment: the second view is a modal. and PS- I am using knockout.js. To access the id, I am using the jquery syntax $('#mapId')[0] syntax, it returns null or undefined. When i use atrribute binding for id, the value gets assigned to the id, but it does not represent a div element(which is required for the map object) but only a string which is equal to the id value.

Comment: Could you post some code on jsfiddle or in your question? I'm thinking  if you're initializing the google map object *before* Knockout has a chance to bind the ID to your element.

Answer (score 20):

You should use a custom binding like so:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.map = {

    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var mapObj = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(
            ko.utils.unwrapObservable(mapObj.lat),
            ko.utils.unwrapObservable(mapObj.lng));
        var mapOptions = { center: latLng,
                          zoom: 5, 
                          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};

        mapObj.googleMap = new google.maps.Map(element, mapOptions);
    }
};
```

Your HTML would look like this:

```html
<div id="mapDiv" data-bind="style:{width:'300px',height:'300px'},map:myMap"></div>
```

Finally your view model:

```js
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.myMap = ko.observable({
        lat: ko.observable(55),
        lng: ko.observable(11)});
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schmidlop/5eTRV/10/) that does a bit more than what you are asking but should work fine for your case as well.

Comment: how do you then push more points in a single map? i tried observableArray but it doesn' work can anyone help me on that ?

Comment: @kougiland - in the binding I've stashed a refence to the google map object in the googleMap property of the view model ('myMap' in the example). You can access it like self.myMap().googleMap and add markers directly. If you want a binding that keeps the map markers in synch with an observable array then you ought to ask a different question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good example of using Knockout JS and Google Maps. Hopefully, it will help get you on the right track.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/387626/BikeInCity-2-KnockoutJS-JQuery-Google-Maps

Answer (score 1):

I have modified "schmidlop" binding to reset marker on change in inputs (lat long inputs) and marker always in center of map.

Html

```
<input data-bind="value: mapOne().lat" />

<input data-bind="value: mapOne().lng" />
```

Binding , Include this in some js file and include it in html.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.map = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
            $("#" + element.getAttribute("id")).data("mapObj","");
            mapObj = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                ko.utils.unwrapObservable(mapObj.lat),
                ko.utils.unwrapObservable(mapObj.lng));
            var mapOptions = { center: latLng,
                              zoom: 12, 
                              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};

            mapObj.googleMap = new google.maps.Map(element, mapOptions);

            mapObj.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: mapObj.googleMap,
                position: latLng,
               draggable: true
            });     

            mapObj.onChangedCoord = function(newValue) {
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                    ko.utils.unwrapObservable(mapObj.lat),
                    ko.utils.unwrapObservable(mapObj.lng));

                mapObj.googleMap.setCenter(latLng);
                mapObj.marker.setPosition(latLng);                 
            };

            mapObj.onMarkerMoved = function(dragEnd) {
                var latLng = mapObj.marker.getPosition();
                mapObj.lat(latLng.lat());
                mapObj.lng(latLng.lng());
            };

            mapObj.lat.subscribe(mapObj.onChangedCoord);
            mapObj.lng.subscribe(mapObj.onChangedCoord);  

            google.maps.event.addListener(mapObj.marker, 'dragend', mapObj.onMarkerMoved);

            $("#" + element.getAttribute("id")).data("mapObj",mapObj);
        }
    };
```

View Model

```
self.mapOne = ko.observable();    


self.mapOne({'lat':ko.observable(87.22),'lng':ko.observable(27.22)});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `mapId` you'll want to use `document.getElementById('map')`, where `'map'` is the id of the div containing the map (`<div id="map"></div>`). [This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/FcSmA/) should help.