# InfoWindow not showing up

Tags: javascript, google-maps, knockout.js

Hello I'm trying to bind Google Maps with Knockout script.
Nearly everything works but I can't force infowindows to show up on event.
Without Knockout my code works but with it doesn't.
Below my js code:

```
var infowindow;
function point(name, lat, long) {
    this.name = name;
    this.lat = ko.observable(lat);
    this.long = ko.observable(long);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
        title: name,
        map: map,
        draggable: true
    });
//if you need the poition while dragging
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function () {
    var pos = marker.getPosition();
    this.lat(pos.lat());
    this.long(pos.lng());
}.bind(this));

//if you just need to update it when the user is done dragging
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {
    var pos = marker.getPosition();
    this.lat(pos.lat());
    this.long(pos.lng());
}.bind(this));
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "empty" });
    console.log("mouseover");
    infowindow.setContent(this.title);
    infowindow.open(map, this);

}.bind(this));


}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(55, 11),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var viewModel = {
    points: ko.observableArray([
        new point('Test1', 55, 11),
        new point('Test2', 56, 12),
        new point('Test3', 57, 13)])

};
function addPoint() {
    viewModel.points.push(new point('a', 58, 14));
}
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Now my question:

Is it simple way to make it works. If yes can anyone suggest me where should I look for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be your use of `this`.

Add `var self = this;` as the first line within point function & use `self` to refer to properties within point.

In the mouseover event, does this refer to the marker, the map, or viewmodel? If the drag event are setting values correctly, then this is the point viewmodel, in which case within the mouseover event you called `this.title`. There is no title...

```
function point(name, lat, long) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.lat = ko.observable(lat);
    self.long = ko.observable(long);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
        title: name,
        map: map,
       draggable: true
    });
    //if you need the poition while dragging
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function () {
        var pos = marker.getPosition();
        self.lat(pos.lat());
        self.long(pos.lng());
    }.bind(this));

    //if you just need to update it when the user is done dragging
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {
        var pos = marker.getPosition();
        self.lat(pos.lat());
        self.long(pos.lng());
    }.bind(this));
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "empty" });
        console.log("mouseover");
        infowindow.setContent(marker.title);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: You are right. There is no this.title. After changing to this.name and using console.log() I can see that it show good name but still no infoWindow. So know I'm sure that problem is in this line: infowindow.open(map, this);

Answer (score 0):

I have never used knockout myself but integrating it with maps does not look simple, here are some reading materials: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/351298/KnockoutJS-and-Google-Maps-binding
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/387626/BikeInCity-2-KnockoutJS-JQuery-Google-Maps
[Google maps and knockoutjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722925/google-maps-and-knockoutjs)

The maps code you have provided looks correct so I assume the issue lies with the knockout integration.