# Adding Google Maps to an Html File and Using It With Knockouts

Tags: javascript, google-maps, knockout.js

I would like to add google maps to my website. I am using KnockoutsJs. After that. I want to get lat/long values of chosen region.

Comment: There is no question asked in this question?

Comment: How could i do this job? How could i add google maps to my project? How could i bind knockout and html?

Comment: What exactly is the problem, what have you tried?
If you are completly new to programming I suggest you start with something simpler.

Comment: I should add a div in html. Maps will show on there. I have an .js file (knockout) and a html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A really quick google revealed: [Google maps and knockoutjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722925/google-maps-and-knockoutjs) http://chadmullins.com/misc-php/knockout-series-three.php and perhaps most usefully: http://hoonzis.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/knockoutjs-and-google-maps-binding.html.

Without further information I can't be more specific.

Comment: google is not defined. I got this message in firebug Whe i add http://jsfiddle.net/schmidlop/5eTRV/10/

Comment: You'll need to import the google maps library... https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial